# ReactJS: how to trigger reducer with action in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

I am working for a reducer test. But the return state from reducer with action function is abnormal.

**reducer.react-test.js**

```
import reducer from '../../test_module/reducer';

describe('Test Reducer', () => {

  const initStatus = { id: -1, list: [] };

  it('1. has default state', () => {    
    expect(reducer(initStatus, { type: 'unexpected' })).toEqual({
      ...initStatus
    });    
  });

  it('2. has added once', () => {    
    expect(reducer(initStatus, { type: "ADD" })).toEqual({
      ...initStatus,
      id: 0,
      list: [0],
    });   
  });

  it('3. has added twice', () => {    
    const afterAddOnce = reducer(initStatus, { type: "ADD" });
    expect(reducer(afterAddOnce, { type: "ADD" })).toEqual({
      ...initStatus,
      id: 1,
      list: [0,1],
    });    
  });
})
```

**reducer.js**

```
export default function reducer(state={
    id: -1, list: [],
  }, action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case "ADD": {
      state.id = state.id + 1;
      state.list.push(state.id);
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

**folder structure**

```
.
├── __test__
│   └── test_module
│       └── reducer.react-test.js
└── test_module
    └── reducer.js
```

My first and second test case works expectedly.

However, while I tried to trigger action twice, I store the return state from first action. But the return state is unexpectedly, which executed `ADD` action twice. (I expected once only)

Thus I got this result while I run `jest`:

```
FAIL  __test__/test_module/reducer.react-test.js
  ● Test Reducer › has added twice

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      {"id": 1, "list": [0, 1]}
    Received:
      {"id": 2, "list": [0, 1, 2]}

    Difference:

    - Expected
    + Received

     Object {
    -  "id": 1,
    +  "id": 2,
       "list": Array [
         0,
         1,
    +    2,
       ],
     }
```

I must misunderstand the usage of trigging reducer function with action. I hope to get some proper way to trigger reducer with action and get expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit can be found in your reducer, specifically these lines:

```
state.id = state.id + 1;
state.list.push(state.id);
```

The reducer here is both mutating the state, and returning a new state. Mutating the state is bad practice, and can cause weird effects (like the one you're experiencing)

So the *'2. has added once'* test will increment the id to 0. This will stay in memory during the next test where *initialStatus* will have an id of 0, not -1. In our reducer, *state* points to *initialStatus*. So calling `state.id = status.id + 1;` increments *initialStatus*'s id field, and same for list. This is why it appears that the ADD action being called three times.

Moving away from mutations in the reducer can help fix this problem.

```
case "ADD": {
    const newId = state.id + 1;

    return {
      id: newId,
      list: state.list.concat([newId])
    };
}
```

Remember, never mutate the state in a reducer, always return the new state instead!
(http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#never-mutate-reducer-arguments)